# Stacked Bar Chart in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a Stacked Bar Graph using ggplot2. Here is how my data looks like

```
Date          Full.Page.Ads Total.Pages
11/10/2015                3          24
12/10/2015               10          24
13/10/2015               15          24
```

This is the code which I am trying to use to visualize the data

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

ns <- read.csv("NS.csv")

ggplot(data=ns, aes(x = Date, y = Total.Pages, fill=Full.Page.Ads)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

But for some reason rather than making a proper stacked bar chart, it keeps making something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPbeU.png. Rather than this I would like to show the main bars as Total.Pages and inside those bars, Full.Page.Ads bar in different colours.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong out here.

This is a sample of what I am aspiring to make http://blog.visual.ly/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/StackedPercent.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to melt your data before plotting. You also need to compute the difference between Total.Pages and Full.Page.Ads if you want your graph to represent the proportion of Full.Page.Ads with respect to the total number of pages. Something like:

```
ns <- data.frame(Date = c("11/10/2015", "12/10/2015", "13/10/2015"),
               Full.Page.Ads = c(3, 10, 15),
               Total.Pages = c(24, 24, 24))

#    Date Full.Page.Ads Total.Pages
# 1 11/10/2015             3          24
# 2 12/10/2015            10          24
# 3 13/10/2015            15          24


ns$not.Full.Page.Ads <- ns$Total.Pages - ns$Full.Page.Ads
ns$Total.Pages <- NULL
ns2 <-melt(ns)

#        Date          variable value
#1 11/10/2015     Full.Page.Ads     3
#2 12/10/2015     Full.Page.Ads    10
#3 13/10/2015     Full.Page.Ads    15
#4 11/10/2015 not.Full.Page.Ads    21
#5 12/10/2015 not.Full.Page.Ads    14
#6 13/10/2015 not.Full.Page.Ads     9

ggplot(data = ns2, aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Can you explain me the logic behind this?